# Drawing SVG Glyphs in Golang to Convert Latex DVI to SVG

Tags: go, svg, latex, dvi

I am looking to render a piece of Latex code via Golang using the [StarTex](https://github.com/go-latex/star-tex) Library. One particular [package](https://github.com/go-latex/star-tex/blob/main/cmd/dvi-cnv/png.go) is used to write the DeVice Independent (DVI) file into a PNG. Unfortunately, a raster image is inadequate for my purposes, so I wished to modify the code to produce an SVG instead. It appears that the only reference to this PNG implementation is at [line 951](https://github.com/go-latex/star-tex/blob/9bb27e8a98c75959b2980c577df4b03dd5196a88/dvi/machine.go#L951) of the DVI implementation.

```
m.rdr.DrawGlyph(cur.h, cur.v, *fnt, rune(cmd), m.color.Color())
```

It appears that the DVI machine only needs to plot a glyph for a rune at the current horizontal and vertical position with a specified font and color. Surely, this one feature could be easily replicated with an SVG format, right? Even if there is no fully fledged SVG library, is there a way to draw a glyph at a specified x and y location? Does anyone have a minimal working example?

Comment: You can look into [dvisvgm](https://dvisvgm.de/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/mgieseki/dvisvgm)), which will convert DVI to SVG (one per page).